# How to trigger an event from injected HTML button in firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

My end goal is to create a firefox extension that inserts an HTML button onto a site and have it fire a function defined in a custom code module in my extension.

I tried to implement Nickolay's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017743/how-to-call-a-function-in-firefox-extension-from-a-html-button). When I click the button I created though I get the following error in Firebug:

"uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMEventTarget.dispatchEvent]" nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)" location: "JS frame :: "

My code:

```
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
    Components.utils.import("chrome://my_ext/content/writeFile.jsm", my_ext);
    //alert(foo());  - foo() is an function in the above code module I import


    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered "onload" event

    var event = doc.createEvent("Events");
    event.initEvent("my-custom-event", true, true);

    var fblike = doc.getElementById("LikePluginPagelet");
    var button = doc.createElement("input");
    button.setAttribute("type", "button");
    button.setAttribute("value", "My Button");
    button.setAttribute('onclick', 'dispatchEvent(event)');

    fblike.appendChild(button, fblike);

    var docx = event.originalTarget;
    if(docx && docx.addEventListener)
        docx.addEventListener("my-custom-event", function() {alert(foo()); }, false);
},
```

My writeFile.jsm:

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["foo"];

function foo() {
    return "foo test";
}
```

Any idea on how I can fix this? I should also mention that I am completely new to developing browser extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. I did not need to add the second listener and it only took one line:
button.addEventListener("click", foo, false);

I had previously tried foo() instead of just foo and that failed but works just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

`button.setAttribute('onclick', 'dispatchEvent(event)')` will not do what you think it will do - when the button is clicked it takes the `click` event and tries to dispatch it. Dispatching an event a second time isn't allowed however. What you seem to want is this:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  button.dispatchEvent(event);
}, false);
```

This creates a function closure that will have access to the variable of the surrounding code - including `button` and `event`. Further reading on closures: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml

Comment: Hmm when I try to implement this I get quite an ambiguous error: "uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://mezz/content/overlay.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 43"  data: no]"
Line 43 refers to the code you suggested ("button.onclick = function() ..."). Googling this error brought me to pages suggesting incompatibility of Firefox though not sure.

Comment: @user773953: Oh, you are injecting that button into a content page. Yes, `onclick` will not be available, you should use `addEventListener` instead (which is usually a good idea anyway). I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. I get no errors now but the button just doesn't work. When I click it nothing happens. To clarify, the last three lines of my original code are still fine right? Starting from "var docx = event.original...".

Comment: Update: Played with it some more and now I finally receive the event ... see remaining problem at end of post. Changes: 1) Changed var 'event' to 'mEvent' (might've been conflicting var) 2) Changed "my-custom-event" to "mClick" ('-' might have caused issue) 3) Got rid of declaration of new var 'docx' and 'if' statement that immediately follows. Instead of 'docx' used 'doc' for last addEventListener. Remaining Problem: alert(foo()) statement still doesn't work. For testing purposes changed to alert("test") and that works but I'm back to square one since that worked before.

Comment: @user773953: Honestly, answering several unrelated questions at once isn't fun - especially when most questions are underspecified. You asked what's wrong with your event dispatching, I answered that question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have been more clear that all I was trying to figure out is how to get the button to call a code module. Thought I hinted at it when I said my end goal but will be more explicit next time.